# Is it possible to direct your output file having the same name as input file, that is to overwrite?

Tags: awk, unix

I would like to overwrite the name of input file with the same name of output file owing to limited disk space that I have in my system. Is it possible? I know this is not recommended, but I have the input files already backup. I will have a loop in a shell to do the cut command.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..1000}
do
    cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=1,3-7 input$i.txt > input$i.txt
done
```

Comment: Can't you use the backup as source?

Answer (score 3):

You could always use a temporary file to which you redirect, and then when you're sure everything went fine, you rename it to the original file.

Comment: Yupp, this is what most tools do.

Comment: It is either this, or read the entire file into memory and then write the output, or hold the output in memory until all of the input is processed. The input data needs to exits somewhere until it is processed and the output created.

Answer (score 2):

some gnu utils commands have a -i option (such as sed) that allow you to change a file in place .....most of file filtering and editing (like cut) can be done using sed.

Answer (score 1):

The shell will parse the command and handle the redirections first.  When it sees "> afile" it will truncate "afile" and open it for writing.  Your data is now destroyed.  *Then* the shell hands the filename to `cut` which now has nothing to read.

This is how I learned:

```
some | pipeline < my_file > my_file.tmp
ln my_file my_file.bak   # this is a hard link
mv my_file.tmp my_file
```

That keeps the original data in place for as long as possible.

If you're having disk space issues, you will have to read the input file into memory entirely.

Answer (score 0):

In case of very limited disk space (disk quota) you could try to place a compressed source file in ram (`/dev/shm`) and use that as the source (uncompressing it to stdout and piping that to your script).